# how can create mega menu in responsive design with bootstrap like an example

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to design a menu like [www.digikala.com/] but in responsive design or with bootstrap . I can't find any example or template . can you show me some template to design a menu like "digikal" menu. and what's name of this menu.

Comment: I don't know where can ask question like this... I saw very bad question in stackoverflow that thay didn't give any negative point!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add the mega menu in bootstrap menu bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838040/how-to-add-the-mega-menu-in-bootstrap-menu-bar)

Comment: it's important to find template like that menu and name of that menu

Comment: please help me I can't create second level of menu for these examples http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/

Answer (score 2):

Extend your bootstrap with **Yamm3** megamenu

Here is link to widget

http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/

And use it like this

```
<nav class="navbar yamm navbar-default " role="navigation">
...
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>
               <div class="yamm-content">
                  <div class="row"> 
                    ...
           </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
...
</nav>
```

Here is working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1698/

Comment: in first I want a sample like (www.digikala.com) menu . I saw a menu like this in first page of google. but I cant find any example

Comment: You can style this menu for your needs

Comment: That's a lot of free work. Why don't you hire someone if you can't do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:

This provides full and full responsive templates

https://wrapbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

I designed my mega menu without hire someone. you can see it here [mega menu in three levels](http://jsfiddle.net/ghandriz2/ggmngjxy/)

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Grid demo navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default yamm">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-grid"
                        class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
                    </span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">buy100</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar-collapse-grid" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">main menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class=" navbar-nav dropdown-menu" >
                            <!-- Grid 12 Menu -->
                            <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">menu1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                                    <li class="grid-demo">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!--With Offsets
    -->
                            <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"> menu2<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                                    <li class="grid-demo">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!--Aside Menu
    -->
                            <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">menu3<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="grid-demo">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!--Nesting Menu
    -->
                            <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">menu4<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="grid-demo">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <br>
                                                <h3>
                                                    3
                                                </h3>
                                                <br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"> lk,,,,</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"> lk,,,,</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"> lk,,,,</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```